# How to pass props to createStyles in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

right now I want to create a component, and pass color and value to the component from its parent. Here, more specifically, ***I want to pass color to styles***, so that I can change color according to parent component. But I got error: **Error TS2339: Property 'color' does not exist on type '{}'**.

```
import React,{FC} from "react";
import {createStyles, makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import {BackstageTheme} from "@backstage/theme";
import {LinearProgress} from "@material-ui/core";


interface OverallHealthProps {
    color?: String;
    value?: number;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles<BackstageTheme>(() =>
    createStyles({
        overAllHealthRoot: {
            height: 30,
            borderRadius: 0
        },
        overAllHealthColorPrimary: {
            //TODO: change color according to theme
            backgroundColor: "#A9A9A9"
        },
        overAllHealthBar: {
            borderRadius: 0
        },
        overAllHealthBarColorPrimary: {
            //Error TS2339: Property 'color' does not exist on type '{}'.
            backgroundColor: props => props.color,
        }
    })

)

const RatingBar: FC<OverallHealthProps> = (props:OverallHealthProps) =>{
    const classes =  useStyles(props);
    return(
        <LinearProgress
            variant="determinate"
            value={props.value}
            classes={{
                root: classes.overAllHealthRoot,
                colorPrimary: classes.overAllHealthColorPrimary,
                bar: classes.overAllHealthBar,
                barColorPrimary: classes.overAllHealthBarColorPrimary
            }}
        />
    )
};


export default RatingBar;
```

Also I tried this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles<BackstageTheme, OverallHealthProps>((BackstageTheme, props:OverallHealthProps)=>
    createStyles({
        overAllHealthRoot: {
            height: 30,
            borderRadius: 0
        },
        overAllHealthColorPrimary: {
            //TODO: change color according to theme
            backgroundColor: "#A9A9A9"
        },
        overAllHealthBar: {
            borderRadius: 0
        },
        overAllHealthBarColorPrimary: {
            //Error TS2339: Property 'color' does not exist on type '{}'.
            backgroundColor: props.color,
        }
    })

)
```

and get error :

**TS2345: Argument of type '(theme: BackstageTheme, props: OverallHealthProps) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Styles<BackstageTheme, OverallHealthProps, string>'.   Type '(theme: BackstageTheme, props: OverallHealthProps) => any' is not assignable to type 'StyleRulesCallback<BackstageTheme, OverallHealthProps, string>'.**

so how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a default color props value to your arrow function. The problem is located at the initialisation because non color is passed to your function.  Try something like this: `makeStyles<BackstageTheme>(({color = "<something>" }) => ...` After you passed the props, the new value will take place.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but  I need my color changed according to props. the color should be a variable right?

Comment: The problem is the initialisation, after you pass the props, the new value will take place. Other way is check if the props exists, and for that you can try use `try-catch` block  @HongliBu

Comment: Answering directly your question, `color` as you used should be an input variable (a key in a props object) of your arrow function

Comment: I tried, it seems not working, I am getting "TS2339: Property 'color' does not exist on type 'BackstageTheme", when I was passing ```{color = "<something>" }```, I think it regard ```{color = "<something>" }``` as BackstageTheme

Comment: Can you add your project to a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io) or [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)? Will be more easy to help you out